# Jetty shows http error message 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jetty, http-status-code-503

I developed a maven module application that works fine using (google appengine; maven; springmvc).

3 weeks after when I  decided to add some features I noticed that I can no longer deploy it on the local, when I try to do so, I get:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE Powered by Jetty://

NB : I did not change the code(so I'm pretty sure that it's not a source code problem), I just installed some applications like jenkins and sonar.

Comment: The stuff you installed probably broke stuff...

Comment: I stoped all thoses services but nothign happens :/

Comment: This happens usually when one of your servlet mappings is broken. You should double-triple-check your web.xml. Could you add it to your post?

Comment: exactly the problem was in the web.xml. thanks you

Comment: Wow, a minor typo in my web.xml was also the cause of this problem. I would never have checked that if I didn't read your comment. Thank you, you saved me hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is [nick's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833295/jetty-shows-http-error-message-503-service-unavailable#comment43258690_25833295):

This happens usually when one of your servlet mappings is broken. You should double-triple-check your web.xml.

Comment: Where is this web.xml file?