# Jetty 9 with Spring 2 compatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to upgraded our framework from Java 6 to Java 8. This consequently required me to upgrade from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9 (embedded)...

When I try to open a page (served by Jetty), I'm getting a "Error 503: Service Unavailable". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28997544/2818782) post suggesting that my servlet mappings are broken, made me wonder if maybe our Spring library is no longer compatible.

**Is Spring 2.5.5 compatible with Java 8 and Jetty 9.3.6?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 2.5 isn't compatible with Java8 and I'm afraid it never will be. See this for some info: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11899

Comment: non-login required link for those that want to read the issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11899